# user has denied the privileges to the code

Tags: java, japplet

I have an applet that run perfectly using eclipse or executing it on a localhost using wamp. All the classes are in a jar file.

But, when I run it in a real webhost I get that error:
"user has denied the privileges to the code"

Comment: For signed code issues, you want to make sure you specify the JDK version and the runtime version. Is http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8029788 related?

Answer (score 0):

Did you transfer all your parameters? For example: If your code is configured at localhost to load some archive, these archive's should be present as parameter-value for your "real webhost", too (e.g. archive="first.jar,second.jar"). The message "user has denied the privileges to the code" is quite confusing, not to say it is complete fail by Oracle Inc. In this case the plugin quits loading the applet, and points the finger to a "user". But the reason would be, that the jar is missing, and the jar contains signed classes.